# Dired-like browser for buffers?

Tags: spacemacs, buffers, kill-buffer

I use Spacemacs, and I often use `SPC b b` to list buffers so that I can kill the buffers I no longer want. Unfortunately, this process takes a while because I have to repeatedly press `SPC b b`, navigate to a buffer I want to kill, open it, and then hit `SPC b d`.

I was looking for something that allows me to open up a list of buffers, in a new buffer, and quickly navigate through them and delete them easily. Kind of like Dired (in Evil mode), which allows you to use `j` and `k` to navigate through the list of files and `D` to delete a file.

Does something like this currently exist in Spacemacs, or in some well-known package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is built-in to emacs. Put `(require 'ibuffer)` in your config file, then bind a key to 'ibuffer:

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'ibuffer)
```

Be sure to check out its help documentation. It has a lot of features.

Comment: `list-buffers` (bound to `C-x C-b` in vanilla emacs) also is a possible choice.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, Ibuffer (`ibuffer`) and Buffer Menu (`buffer-menu`) are the closest to a Dired-like interface.  But you can also list and act on multiple buffers using just completion.

With [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), commands that show you buffer names for completion let you use **`S-<delete>`** on any number of them to kill those buffer.

Similarly, **`C-x k`** (`icicle-kill-buffer`, in Icicle mode) lets you kill any number of buffers during the same command.

See:

- [Buffer-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input) for more about buffer-name completion
- [Multi-Commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) for info about acting on multiple completion candidates during the same command

Answer (score 0):

From HELM Mini (`SPC b b`), you can do `C-c d` to kill a buffer without exiting HELM Mini.

Comment: You can also mark a buffer with C-SPC, so you can mark multiple buffers in the Helm Mini-buffer and then delete them all. This is all built into 'vanilla' spacemacs with helm.

Comment: @mclear after marking the buffers with C-SPC, how do I kill them?

Comment: I use Shift-option-D. If you're not on OS X it might be Shift-command-D