# How to select buffers for deletion

Tags: buffers

How can I delete multiple buffers from a buffer list?

I can select the ones I want to delete using C-s, but can't figure if I can mark them for subsequent deletion.

Is there a way?

Comment: See [Operating on several buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Several-Buffers.html) in the Emacs manual. You can do it with either with `buffer-menu` or with `ibuffer` - see e.g. [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29650/dired-like-browser-for-buffers) for these (and some other) possibilities.